# 'orderby' multiple meta keys/values on pre_get_post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Scenario:
i have an archive-job.php template and a pre_get_post function:

```
function cbk_job_archive_override($query) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'job' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('orderby', 'menu_order');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
}
```

the 'job' post type has 2 additional custom meta fields, 'cmb_job_featured' and 'cmb_job_publishdate' which i would like to order by instead of menu_order.

the 'cmb_job_featured' custom meta field could have either a 'yes' or 'no' value

the 'cmb_job_publishdate' custom meta field is saved in this date format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'

i need all posts which have 'cmb_job_featured' set to yes to be displayed first and then all other posts to be displayed by 'cmb_job_publishdate' with most recent first.

i need to edit my pre_get_post function to some how combine:

```
$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
$query->set( 'meta_key', 'cmb_job_featured' );
$query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
```

and

```
$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
$query->set( 'meta_key', 'cmb_job_publishdate' );
$query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
```

Comment: First of all, your date format is incorrect in your custom field. The only usable date format is yyyy/mm/dd if you are going to sort by that date. Secondly, you cannot order by two different custom fields, although you can order by two different parameters. Would be great if this parameter can be extended in future to do so. The only solution I can think of is to use `usort` on the returned array of posts in the `the_posts` filter

Comment: and how would i do that?